# In multiprocess module of python , how to find which worker process has executed the job

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there any way to find out , which worker process among the Pool has executed a specific job .

For example,

```
def start_exe():
    #execute some bunch of statements 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    result = p.apply.async(start_exe)
    print result.get()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any API for that, but you can embed the name of the process that did the job in the result:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process

def start_exe():
    return 'done', current_process().name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    result = p.apply_async(start_exe)

    print result.get()
```

Example output:

```
('done', 'PoolWorker-4')
```